# How to detect whether a protocol is supported through web browser?

Tags: javascript, scripting, protocols

Similar to iTunes' 'Link Maker' (http://www.apple.com/itunes/linkmaker/faq/). Through web browser, iTunes webpages is capable of finding out if `itms://` has been registered on client workstation, hence displaying correct message ('View in iTunes' button or 'Download iTunes' promotion banner).

How is this conducted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is really no easy way to do this. iTunes actually uses the following [script](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/detection/itmsCheck.js) to do the detection. From the code you can see they use a browser plug-in within each web browser to accomplish this.

In Internet Explorer, there is a feature via the [protocolLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741838%28VS.85%29.aspx) property, which can be used, but obviously it's browser specific.

There may be other hacks available, but I think some sort on browser plug-in would be the surest solution.