# How can browser support for itms links be detected?

Tags: javascript, safari, itunes-store

How can I detect whether a user's browser supports iTunes Music Store (`itms://`) links?

If the browser supports it, I'd like to offer an `itms://` link, so that it will open directly in iTunes. But for browsers that don't, I'd link to the object using `https://itunes.apple.com`.

I thought about offering `itms://` only to Safari, but then realized that (at least on a Mac) Chrome also seems to support `itms://`. Also, detecting Safari [seems a bit fragile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12625944/93995). If possible I'd prefer to detect feature support rather than checking for a specific browser.

Comment: See the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411875/how-to-detect-whether-a-protocol-is-supported-through-web-browser

Comment: It also appears that this JS script might work:
https://github.com/n0s/itunesdetect/blob/master/itunesdetect.js

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this script](https://github.com/n0s/itunesdetect/blob/master/itunesdetect.js), which I founded immediately after posting, and which [@Lawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283816/lawson) also recommended.

**Update**: does not seem to work with IE on Windows 8. It fails to detect iTunes integration on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use "Inspect Element" on Google Chrome, etc, you would find the following javascript that uses a function called `its.detect.iTunesDetected()`.

External scripts needed are from apple's website:
[https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/EF6B/web-storefront-base.js](https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/B2B2/web-storefront-base.js)
[https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/EF6B/web-storefront-preview.js](https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/B2B2/web-storefront-preview.js)

```
<script>
        if(its.detect.itunesDetected()) alert("iTunes Installed");
</script>
```

[Example Code.](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ6F7/3/)

Hope this helps.